# Bind whole property of google maps so codebehind can add - C# .Net Maui

Tags: c#, google-maps, maui

I'm looking for a way to create a google map in the codebehind of my app, and bind to the codebehind map in xaml.

This is my Mapper.xaml currently, but I would like a way to bind to the whole property of the map to be referenced in codebehind. It's currently creating the property in xaml:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CellularSignal1"
             xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps;assembly=Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps"
             x:Class="CellularSignal1.Mapper"
             x:DataType="local:Mapper"
             x:Name="Mapper"
             Title="Mapper">
    <maps:Map x:Name="map"/>
    <!--Would like something like...
    <maps:Map Reference="{Binding=googleMaps}"/>
    -->
</ContentPage>
```

Meaning, don't create a new property in xaml, just reference to a property in codebehind. If I could do something like this I would then have in my codebehind...

```
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps;

public partial class Mapper : ContentPage
{
    Map googleMapper;

    public Mapper()
    {
       Location location = new Location(36.9628066, -122.0194722);
       MapSpan mapSpan = new MapSpan(location, 0.01, 0.01);
       googleMapper = new Map(mapSpan);
       InitializeComponent;
       // Add a bunch of other stuff to map.
       addPins();
     }
}
```

the reason I want to do something like this in the first place is that I have used what it is currently, and then referenced the `map`, and moved to region upon startup, but there is a delay in moving to the new region vs what the default location is. I'm trying to see if I can remove this delay by initializing the map with the location to go to.

Comment: Can `this.Content = googleMapper;` work for you? And if you uesd the map in the stacklyout. You can use `stacklayout.Children.Clear` to remove the map and use `stacklayout.Children.Add()` to add new instance of the map.

Comment: this.Content wouldn't work only because I don't want my whole page populated by the map. I want other elements on the page. I haven't tried adding it as a child, yet. I will try that.

Comment: All right, looking forward to your reply.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the Map in the code behind such as:

In the xaml:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CellularSignal1"
             xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps;assembly=Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps"
             x:Class="CellularSignal1.Mapper"
             x:DataType="local:Mapper"
             x:Name="Mapper"
             Title="Mapper">
</ContentPage>
```

In the code behind:

```
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps;

public partial class Mapper : ContentPage
{
    Map googleMapper;

    public Mapper()
    {
       Location location = new Location(36.9628066, -122.0194722);
       MapSpan mapSpan = new MapSpan(location, 0.01, 0.01);
       googleMapper = new Map(mapSpan);
       InitializeComponent;
       // Add a bunch of other stuff to map.
       addPins();
      
      this.Content = googleMapper;
     }
}
```

Comment: I tried that last comment, but with OnAppearing with a conditional (since I only want to set some stuff once), but it seems like map doesn't re-instantiate with map=googleMapper.

Comment: Sorry for my careless, I have tested just not. The `map=googleMapper` will not re-instantiate. So you may need to use the `this.Content = googleMapper;`. The controls declared in the xaml seems can be re-set properties but can not re-instantiate. So you can reset the page's content. @rickster26ter1